# Trying to scrape a website with Axios and I'm getting a 429 Too Many Requests error

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, axios

Trying to scrape a site using Axios and (eventually) Cheerio). But I can't even get a response from the server with Axios. Simple code here results in a 429 Too Many Requests error.

```
const axios = require('axios');

async function scrape(url) {
    try {
        // Fetch HTML
        const { data } = await axios.get(url);
        console.log(`Data: ${data}`);
        // Load HTML
        const $ = cheerio.load(data);
    } catch (err) { console.error(err); }
}

scrape('https://www.realestate.com.au/rent/in-qld/list-1?activeSort=list-date');
```

I'm sure there's something I'm missing, but I figured the async/await would avoid any timing issues.

I've tried a number of wait patterns with Axios but nothign seems to work for this site.

Comment: a single request results in that error?